# Transform field values into column names and fill them with a combination of values that match certain criteria

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below:

```
product<-c("ab","ab","ab","ac","ac","ac")
shop<-c("sad","sad","sad","sadas","fghj","xzzv")
category<-c("a","a","a","b","b","b")
tempr<-c(35,35,14,24,14,5)
value<-c(0,0,-6,8,4,0)
store<-data.frame(product,shop,category,tempr,value)



product  shop category tempr value
1      ab   sad        a    35     0
2      ab   sad        a    35     0
3      ab   sad        a    14    -6
4      ac sadas        b    24     8
5      ac  fghj        b    14     4
6      ac  xzzv        b     5     0
```

I want to transform this dataframe in a way that I will keep the unique `product` names and turn `shop` names from field values to column names. I want to fill this data frame with a combination of `tempr` and its relative `value` but only for the value that is not 0 otherwise the cells should be empty. The cells should also be empty in case that a product does not exist in a shop. An example of the final form is:

```
store2
  product    sad sadas  fghj xzzv
1      ab 14(-6)                 
2      ac        24(8) 14(4)
```

This could be an approach:

```
library(reshape2)
store2<-dcast(store, product ~ shop,value.var=value)
```

Comment: what if there exists product (e.g. `ab`) in the same shop (e.g. `sad`) that has two rows with non-zero elements in the `value` column ?

Comment: it will always be one like the example df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the answer below. However, I noticed you have records that have the same `product` and `shop`, but different `tempr` and `value` numbers. They will overwrite each other in the format you specified, and therefore also in my example. How do you want to deal with these records?

```
store2 <- matrix(NA,ncol=length(unique(store$shop)),nrow=length(unique(store$product)))
colnames(store2) <- unique(store$shop)
rownames(store2) <- unique(store$product)

for(i in 1:ncol(store)) {
  store2[store[i,'product'],store[i,'shop']] <- paste0(store[i,c('tempr')],'(',store[i,'value'],')')
}
```

NB: as 'empty value' I am now using NA, as it is R's representation and recommended coding for missing values. You could use `store2 <- matrix('',ncol=......)` instead for a blank field

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the final data frame there should only displayed tempr with value different than 0. everything else should either "NA" or empty. In general if this happens( same name,same shop but different tmpr-value) the non zero case should prevail.

Comment: You anserwed to the original question so it is fair to accept the answer. I will create a new Q for this side-issue. Feel free to help. Thanks!